# Update a table with its relations in TypeOrm

Tags: database, postgresql, typeorm

#### We have:

**Postgres Database**

**Photo:**

```
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, ManyToOne} from "typeorm";
import {User} from "./User";

@Entity()
export class Photo {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    url: string;

    @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.photos)
    user: User;

}
```

**User:**

```
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, OneToMany} from "typeorm";
import {Photo} from "./Photo";

@Entity()
export class User {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @OneToMany(() => Photo, photo => photo.user)
    photos: Photo[];

}
```

**Tables:**

```
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
|                         photo                           |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
| id          | int(11)      | PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT |
| url         | varchar(255) |                            |
| userId      | int(11)      | FOREIGN KEY                |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+

+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
|                          user                           |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
| id          | int(11)      | PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT |
| name        | varchar(255) |                            |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
```

**So one user might have several photos.**

**I'd like to update one user and also update their photos (which is a different table).**

Here is how to update a user:

```
await getRepository(User).update({ id }, userData);
```

**The question is how to also update the user's photos?**

*Note that there might be a problem when the user currently has 3 photos, but you're setting 2 for example. So you're reducing the number of photos.*

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following style:

```
const user = await getRepository(User).findOne(id);

user.name = newUserName;
user.photos = [photo1, photo2];

await user.save();
```